# java.net.URL refer to a file in a parent directoty

Tags: java, file, path

I have a very basic question. I need a URL object but the file is in the previous directory relative to the project.

For instance, if I do

```
File testFile = new File("../../data/myData.xml");
```

works perfectly fine, it finds the file

However,

```
URL testURL = new URL("file:///../../data/myData.xml")
```

gives an

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /../../data/myData.xml

Any idea, how to solve, work around this? without changing the position of the data?

Thanks a lot in advance
Altober

Comment: You need to give the complete path to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

`URL testURL = new File("../../data/myData.xml").toURI().toURL();`

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
    URL testUrl = new URL("file://C:/Users/myName/Desktop/abc.txt");
    System.out.println(testUrl.toString());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

    }
}
```

The above code is working file, just tested it, so you need to use file:// and if possible try full path

Comment: thanks a lot but the idea was to try to avoid absolute paths, since it is a project shared by many developers.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /../../data/myData.xml

Note that it is looking for parent directory of root directory, not of current directory.

I dont know if File URLs can refer to relative paths, try

‘new URL("file://../../data/myData.xml")'‘

Comment: "I dont know if File URLs can refer to relative paths" <-- no they cannot. Paths in absolute URIs (and therefore URLs) are always absolute. That is, if you do not use _relative_ URIs.

Comment: I tried that. It seems that fge is right. Lakshman has the right answer. Thank you for your time.